# Django Multi Checkbox form

Tags: python, django, forms, checkbox

There has to be a better way to write this code. Basically, i have a list of emails in my database. I'm struggling to make a neat form, that will have *separated emails checkboxes* by year and by type. For example

First year students
Checkbox Checkbox

Second year students:
.......

My model looks like this

```
class Email(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 254)
    email = models.EmailField(unique = True)
    year = models.IntegerField(default=0
    course = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    type = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

And the only way currently i managed to do this by writing many forms like this

```
class Emailform1(forms.Form):
    my_models = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                                      widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                      queryset=None)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Emailform1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['my_models'].queryset = Email.objects.filter(course = 1).filter(type="Type")
```

But this makes a big hassle working with a ton of forms in the view and etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use many forms - you can use one with many fields:

```
def get_courses_types():
    results = []
    courses = [1, 2, 3]
    types = ['Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3']
    for course in courses:
        for type in types:
            results.append((course, type))
    return results

class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Emailform, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for course, type in get_courses_types():
            field = 'field_{}_{}'.format(course, type)
            self.fields[field] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, 
                queryset=Email.objects.filter(course=course).filter(type=type)
            )
```

And then:

```
form = EmailForm(data=request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    for course, type in get_courses_types():
        value = form.cleaned_data['field_{}_{}'.format(course, type)]
        # save value as you want
```